# Is bincode serialization of an enum with no data in the variants as optimized as referencing a static value?

Tags: enums, rust, static, compiler-optimization, serde

I sometimes use [`serde`](https://serde.rs/) and [`bincode`](https://github.com/servo/bincode) this way:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use bincode;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum PlainDryEnum {
    FirstVariant,
    Second,
    Third,
}

fn example() {
    let message = bincode::serialize(&PlainDryEnum::Second)
        .expect("Could not serialize variant.");
}
```

Whenever I serialize one of these variants, I think

> hey.. the actual content of `message` is statically known, maybe I should make it `const` or at least [`lazy_static`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs), so I would not rely on a useless dynamic call to `serialize`.

Then I think

> well.. I guess I could also do the same for every variant in `PlainDryEnum`. Try it with a macro.

Finally I think

> wait a minute.. is this not a job for the compiler?

Should I worry about this level of optimization? Does the compiler optimize away the call to `serialize` in this case, and just replace (in spirit) this code with a constant?

```rust
let message = &1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bincode::serialize`](https://github.com/servo/bincode/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L98) is not [const fn](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0911-const-fn.html) so it can not be guaranteed to be executed at compile time. That means there is no guarantee that the compiler will replace the call.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question being asked: *Is serialization of a plain enum as optimized as referencing a static slice?*

Comment: @Shepmaster, as I understand the question is "Does rustc optimize away the call to serialize in this case, and just replace (in spirit) this code with `let message = &1;`?". The answer is NO it doesn't optimize away the call to serialize. Have I missed something?

Comment: Assuming that because something is not `const fn` implies that the compiler cannot optimize it is incorrect. For example, [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8d5f95bc417210d0d67479f0f3299390) **cannot** be `const fn` but `example` is optimized to a literal value when you inspect the assembly.

Comment: In provided example I found `callq playground::fib` in assembler listing. I guess it's a call of `fn fib(...)` in runtime. My assembler-foo is very weak so may be my assumption is incorrent. Does it?

Comment: Ah, you'll need to switch to release mode to get the optimizer to be more proactive. You are right that `callq` is a function call though.

Comment: @Shepmaster @MaxV Thank you for clarifications :) I understand that this call is not "guaranteedly" optimized away. Should I report this to `serde` (or `bincode`) (or `rust`) so it may become be the case one day? Meanwhile, is it good practise to write a macro myself to optimize this? Unless there are predefined macros out there to handle this very case?

Comment: @iago-lito, there is what Donald Knuth says "premature optimization is the root of all evil". So if you are sure it's a bottleneck then you have to optimize that part. Otherwise it may be better to concentrate on a real bottlenecks. 

P.S. I believe that when `const fn` features will be stable enough then bincode will propagate `serialize` to be const fn and you'll achieve that kind of optimization for free.

Comment: Okay, cheers :) I totally agree with Knuth on that point. My current situation would rather be "*have a peep under the hood and you shall know Rust better*" ;) So actually, not even a glimpse of bottleneck in sight!